# Compare date and time in javascript using time in milliseconds since epoch

Tags: javascript, date, time, comparison, epoch

Is it a good practice to compare the date and time using the epoch(UTC) time?
I checked it on internet, but did not got example of this. Does this approach has any negative?

```
if(date_utc1>dateutc2){
  //do something
 }
```

Here date_utc1 and date_utc2 are time in epoch

Comment: Time in epoch? Epoch is Jan 1, 1970. I think you mean time in milliseconds since the epoch. What are you comparing them for? What is your question in relation to a particular problem?

Comment: Yeah sorry,i meant time in milliseconds since epoch.

Comment: i need to compare my system time with data received from server which gives hourly weather details and then pick up the data which is after my system date and time

Comment: That seems like a valid solution to me, especially if the data returned from the server is already in the milliseconds-since-epoch format. Is it?

Comment: yes,the data is in milliseconds-since-epoch

Comment: Thanks @J.Titus.. i will use this

Comment: No problem @sandhu. If you wouldn't mind, I added an answer so you can mark the question as resolved.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Date.now()` to get the current time in all recent browsers. You could also use `+new Date()` to obtain the same number in older browsers if you need to.

Since the data returned from the server is already a number in this milliseconds-since-epoch format, it makes sense to use this information for comparisons, since there is no other calculations or parsing of the data coming from the server that must be done.

I don't believe there are any negatives here.

Answer (score 2):

I gathered from the comments that one of the dates is a server-side generated date, but the other is a client-side generated date. Without fully understanding the logic involved here, I´d just like make a short note (sorry don´t have reps for comments) that these two clocks may not fully agree on time (represented in epoch or not).

If possible, a better solution is to only rely on *one* (the server´s) clock. When the client initially receives data from server, the client persist the server-side timestamp (needs to be part of the response). Down the line, if the client wants to check if the server has more data, the persisted value should be sent back. This way we are sure that the server only returns stuff that has been changed since the last fetch.